# how to create a uuid parameter in java which holds the value of ntp time

Tags: java, uuid, ntp

I have to create a parameter of type uuid, but here the problem is this uuid parameter should hold the value of combination of `ntp time` and `integer` values

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeStamp;
import java.util.*;

public class NtpTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer value = new Integer(8);
    TimeStamp ntp = TimeStamp.getCurrentTime();
    // Here I have to create a UUID parameter by combining these value and ntp 
   // I tried with fllowing but got Invalid UUID string error
    UUID uid = UUID.fromString(value+ntp.toString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get exact solution but tried some research, finally found converting `ntp timestamp` to `UUID`

```
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeStamp;

public class NtpToUuid {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeStamp t2 = TimeStamp.getCurrentTime();
    UUID uuid3 = com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.startOf(t2.getTime());
    System.out.println("UUID3 : "+uuid3);
        }
}
```